# What is the optimal way to only sync certain file extensions and exclude other file extensions between separate git branches?

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

Given 3 branches say master, b1, and b2.
The master branch only cares about *.txt files. It needs to ignore everything else.
Branch b1 only needs what is included by master and say *.h, *.c, *.cpp files, and ignore everything else.
Branch b2 also only needs to include the ones included by master and say *.jpg, *.png, *.html, *.css etc. ignoring everything else.

In short, master branch contains information only common to all branches. Example use case: Branch b1 is used to generate output files to be consumed by branch b2, but both contain some information shared with master.

So, what is the optimal way to sync only those common files between master, b1, and b2, and have each branch to only include certain file extensions in its branch and ignore everything else it doesn't need?

I also looked at alternatives of having separate git repos or submodules or subtrees, but the directory structures or nesting patterns created little difficulties. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with this because it's perhaps more useful:

> Is there a better way to solve this problem?

You could, in theory, not bother with a `master` branch at all.  Have three branches, none of which holds final-assembled-results.  Do the assembly outside of Git.  If desired, make an "orphan branch" (or use a tag) to record the assembled result, or just keep the assembled results in a completely different repository.  But these all result in those sorts of little difficulties you mention.

#### What goes wrong

Git simply doesn't work the way you want: you cannot (usefully anyway) "care about" some files and have other "uncared-about" files with the "caring" switching around based on the branch.  That's because "branches", in the sense you're using the word, **do not exist**.

Now, that's a strong statement and it needs justification.  Clearly, branches do exist.  The problem lies in the meaning of the word *branch*.  It has too many meanings and people just sort of flip between them, without realizing that they're doing this, and that gets them into trouble.  (See also [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)) So let's just avoid the term by using what Git really uses: commit hash IDs.

When you run:

```
git checkout br2
```

you're telling Git to do two things:

- save the name `br2` for future use;
- turn the name `br2` into a *commit hash ID*, and extract—which includes "caring about"—a *snapshot of all files* from that commit.

The *second* step is the one that really matters right now: the first one is only needed later, when you run `git commit` to make a *new* commit, or some other Git command that needs the name (`git branch` or `git status` or `git rebase`, for instance).

With one exception—which you see in a fresh clone that hasn't yet run `git checkout`—Git always has some commit checked out *right now*.  Your `git checkout` tells Git: *sweep away the one we have right now, and get me some other commit as the checked-out commit*.

Let's say that right now, you have `br1` checked out, which is commit `b100` right now.  Later, the *name* `br1` may mean some *other* commit, but right now it means that one.  You run `git checkout br2`, which tells Git to switch from commit `b100` to commit `b200` as that's the one that the *name* `br2` means *right now*.<sup>1</sup>

OK, no big deal yet, right?  We're moving from commit `b100` to commit `b200`.  Commit `b100` has in it the `*.h` files and *omits* the `*.jpg` files entirely.  So Git "cares about" the `*.h` files while we have `b100` out.  Those files are *tracked*, which means they're in the (single) index.  We're moving off `b100` though, to `b200`, which has the `*.jpg` files and *omits* the `*.h` files.  Git has to copy the `*.jpg` files *into* its index and *remove* the `*.h` files *from* its index, which means it has to remove the `*.h` files from your work-tree too.

So far, this is all going great: you get just what you want.  But now you want to get to `master` and assemble the pieces.  The name `master` means some other commit, maybe `a123` at the moment.

No matter how you get to `master`, from `br1` (`b100` at the moment) or `br2` (`b200`) at the moment, you don't have *all* the `*.h` *and* `*.jpg` files.  You can only get one set or another.  The underlying problem here is that the "caring about" happens because the files are in Git's *index*.  Listing files in a `.gitignore` file, which is what you do to keep them from getting *into* Git's index, only helps if they're not already there—and when you switch to a commit that *has* the files, Git *will* put them into Git's index, regardless of what's in a `.gitignore` file.  When you switch to a commit that *omits* the files, Git *will* remove them from Git's index, regardless of what's in a `.gitignore` file.

The index's contents reflect the commit you check out.  Each commit has a full snapshot of every file that's in that commit.  That snapshot winds up in Git's index.  Unless you change them—with `git add`, or `git rm`, or by doing another `git checkout` that replaces them wholesale, for instance—those are the files that will go into the *next* commit.

Last, when you use `git merge` to combine work, Git:

- finds a merge base commit;
- compares the two branch tip commits against this merge base; and
- uses that to figure out what to put into the new commit.

The new commit, like any commit, has a snapshot of *all* the files: all the files that were in Git's index at the time `git merge` made the merge commit, and those files are the result of the combining process above.  Merge commits are the same as any other commit: they have a snapshot and metadata.  The only thing that makes them special—makes them merge commits—is that they have two (or more) parent commit hash IDs listed in their metadata.

These interlocking behaviors get in the way:  Either `master` actually *does* have all the files, in which case, the other commits found by other branch names also need to have all the files, or `master` doesn't have *any* of the files, in which case the other branches can be exclusive like this but you can't merge them back *into* `master`, because the common commit that Git will find, that will act as the merge base, will cause them to *add* the files *to* the new commit that goes into `master`—and now `master` has all the files!  If you *remove* them as you go back into the branches, merging will *remove* the files this time.

Ultimately, Git is all about *commits*.  It's the *commits* that determine, well, everything!  The commits *are* snapshots-plus-metadata.  All a *branch name* does is find one particular commit: the last one on some chain.  Commits can be reached from *more than one branch name*, and many, or most, commits are on multiple branches simultaneously.  So the *name* has nothing to do with which files are in the commit: it literally *can't* when more than one name finds that commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Branch name to commit hash ID mappings *change*, which is how branches grow in Git.  Git is built to add new commits, so the normal way that a name changes is that it now means a newer commit that leads, via the commit graph, back to the old commit—and many more commits too.  See also [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).